# Grabbing Text from Sublime Text Regions

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I'm new to creating Sublime Text 3 Plugins and I'm trying to understand the Plugin API that's offered. I want to be able to "grab" text I highlight with my mouse and move it somewhere else. Is there a way I can do this using the Sublime Text Plugin API?

So far, all I've done is be able to create a whole region:

```
allcontent = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
```

I've tried to grab all of the text in the region and put it into a lot file:

```
logfile = open("logfile.txt", "w")
logfile.write(allcontent)
```

But unsuccessfully of course as the log file is blank after it runs.

I've looked over google and there is not a lot of documentation, except for the unofficial documentation, in which I can't find a way to grab the text. Nor are there many tutorials on this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Region` just represents a region of text (i.e. from position 0 to position 10), and isn't tied to any specific view.

To get the underlying text from the view's buffer, you need to call the `view.substr` method with the region as a parameter.

```py
import os
logpath = os.path.join(sublime.cache_path(), 'logfile.txt')
allcontent = self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))
with open(logpath, 'w') as logfile:
    logfile.write(allcontent)
print('written buffer contents to', logpath)
```

To get the region represented by the first selection, you can use `self.view.sel()[0]` in place of `sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())`.

Comment: I've already asked the question, if you want you can check it out [here :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47483393/sublime-text-3-creating-plugin-adding-external-python-libraries)